# Sprites Colliding with an UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
       UIImageView* debrisView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:object];
       if(CGRectIntersectsRect(debrisView.frame, player.frame)){
        NSLog(@"hit");
        }
```

My sprites just ghost through my UIImageView. That's the code I am using to hopefully detect that the two things are hitting. I have all the objects randomly spawning at the top and trickling down. What is wrong with my code?

in my - (void)viewDidLoad method, I have

```
debris = [UIImage imageNamed:@"object.png"];
```

Comment: When are you using your code ? You have to check collision at each frames...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSLog` `debrisView.frame` and `player.frame`, see if they both have their frames set. Also you will get a clearer picture of what is wrong with your code.

[EDIT] Ok to make things easier:

```
-(void) printFrame:(CGRect frame)
{
   NSLog(@"origin = (%f, %f)\n size = (%f, %f)", frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height) 
}
```

use it like this:

```
[self printFrame:debrisView.frame];
[self printFrame:player.frame];
```

Comment: I added NSLog("@%f %f", debrisView.frame, player.frame);
I saw that I just got really big numbers, I'm not seeing what you're trying to say. Explain please? I'm pretty new to objective c.

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(debrisView.frame));`